# pandas dataframe timeseries:linegraph per day

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

First of all: Although quite experienced in SPSS, I'm an absolute beginner in Python and Pandas. I'm trying to learn it because I think it's far more versatile and flexible...

Couldn't find a Python forum for dummies ;) so I hope you can help...

My question:
I've got a dataframe with traffic-data per period of 5 minutes:

```
In[37]: df.head(3)
Out[37]: 
                     RWS01_MONIBAS_0121hrr0070ra_speed  \
time                                                     
2014-09-29 15:00:00                         101.124752   
2014-09-29 15:05:00                         100.626442   
2014-09-29 15:10:00                         102.247742   

                     RWS01_MONIBAS_0121hrr0070ra_flow  \
time                                                     
2014-09-29 15:00:00                              1824   
2014-09-29 15:05:00                              2184   
2014-09-29 15:10:00                              1908   

In[38]: df.tail(3)
Out[38]: 
                     RWS01_MONIBAS_0121hrr0070ra_speed  \
time                                                     
2014-10-03 19:45:00                          99.089214   
2014-10-03 19:50:00                         101.561825   
2014-10-03 19:55:00                         101.178173   

                     RWS01_MONIBAS_0121hrr0070ra_flow  \
time                                                     
2014-10-03 19:45:00                               804   
2014-10-03 19:50:00                              1128   
2014-10-03 19:55:00                              1284
```

The dataframe consists of multiple days (in this example 4, but this is only a test-set) and is indexed on time. What I'm trying to do is to split the dataframe per *date*, and create a linegraph per date.

When I try to select a part from the dataframe and create a graph with df.plot, I get a graph with all the days, whatever I do. What am I doing wrong?

part of code:

```
df['day']=pd.DatetimeIndex(df['time']).day
#select a specific day
select=pd.Series(['23'])
df[df.day.isin(select)]
df.plot(kind='line',y=2)
plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance for your help,
Niels

Comment: what do you currently have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of issues:

1. You are plotting the original frame instead of filtered one

   df[df.day.isin(select)].plot(kind='line',y=2)
2. Day column is an integer datatype

   select=pd.Series([23])

This is the best place to start
http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023784.do